# node.js iisnode https 500 HRESULT 0x6d subStatus 1013

Tags: node.js, iis, socket.io, iisnode

I'm currently working on a realtime chat with socket.io and node.js.
On my development machine everything works fine. I can call my socket.io-server on port 888.

The same port is free and reachable on my production server.

I can't figure out why IIS raises an 500 error. Has anyone an idea?

Following error is thrown:

```
HRESULT: 0x6d
HTTP status: 500
HTTP subStatus: 1013
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
```

Comment: Hi, would you mind sharing your web.config that allowed you to use socket.io on a production server? I cannot get it to work.

Comment: @333 the config looks like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
   <add name="node" path="*.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
  <iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" devErrorsEnabled="true" loggingEnabled="true">
  </iisnode>

  <webSocket enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was that my IIS hosted site run on 443 https. On node.js I wanted also to use https with the same .pfx file. This doesn't seem to work.

Also there is no need to use https for node.js if the site is hosted in SSL environment. The connection runs over wss and is secured.

Instead of `require('https')` I came up with `require('http')`.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me!!